# Run `bundle install` to install missing gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install a Ruby based tool call [Warvox](https://github.com/rapid7/warvox) and when I try to do a "make", I get the following error

```
user@localhost:/home/warvox$ sudo make database
Could not find lumberjack-1.0.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
make: *** [database] Error 7
```

So I had installed Lumberjack

```
user@localhost:/home/warvox$ gem install lumberjack
Successfully installed lumberjack-1.0.9
Parsing documentation for lumberjack-1.0.9
Done installing documentation for lumberjack after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

However ever after installing the missing gem, error is still the same. Any advise/suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

**Step One: Install Bundler**

Open a terminal window on a computer connected to the internet and cd to the application directory, then, enter the following at the command line.

```
$ gem install bundler
```

**Step Two: Install Required Gems**

Ask bundle to install all the gems specified in the Gemfile to your application.

```
$ bundle install
```

If you are using a database in development mode that is different from the database to be used in production mode, use this instead:

```
$ bundle install --without production
```

Reference link  https://www.realifewebdesigns.com/web-programming/rubyonrails/gem-bundler.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are making database as superuser (using `sudo`.)

Hence you should install the missing gem as the same user:

```
sudo gem install lumberjack
```

Uh, sorry, I misread original error message. You should run `bundle install`, possibly as superuser, in the top Warvox source directory.

**UPD: BTW, why are running make database` as superuser, despite what is written in the installation instructions?**

Comment: Thanks. I tired. But still no luck.  when i do `bundle install` I see lumberjack-1.0.9

Comment: When I do a `sudo bundle install` now I get the following error `NoMethodError: undefined method spec for nil:NilClass
An error occurred while installing lumberjack (1.0.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install lumberjack -v 1.0.9 succeeds before bundling.
` i think i need to google some more - new to ruby :)

Comment: You should start from the scratch and instead of `sudo make database` run just `make database`. This `sudo` screws everything up.

Comment: I tried the entire thing from scratch. Now when I do `make database` - I get the following error `Checking the database..
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.
Makefile:20: recipe for target database failed
make: *** [database] Error 7
` Any suggestions here? I'm new to ruby and struggling with this for few hours

Comment: I was able to resolve the above error by doing an update - `bundle update rake` Now I have a few more errors `-- execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS intarray")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "intarray"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.`

Comment: Incase if anyone is following this thread, above issue resolved-  The error was due to the warvox postgresql account not having sufficient rights. `sudo su - postgres
createuser -s -l -d -P warvox
createdb warvox
exit
make database` Thanks @mudasobwa for your help

Comment: Fine everything was resolved. It would be good if you’ll answer your own question with the steps that led to the success and accept it for the future visitors, after this I will be able to remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gem install bundler -v "$(grep -A 1 "BUNDLED WITH" Gemfile.lock | tail -n 1)"
```

I'm using this command and it's work for me